# Did anybody verify if including the word "Drupal" in the name of drupal.SE is under an automatic license?

Tags: support

Websites have some limitations on the usage of the word "Drupal" in their name (I believe it applies also to the domain name). [Drupal trademark and policy](http://drupal.com/trademark) describes exactly in which cases an automatic license is granted.
Did anybody verify if drupal.SE falls under the automatic license cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this use of the mark 'Drupal' would fall under the use described as "fostering the Drupal software."

If you look at some of the examples for this category such as:

- a website "drupalhalloffame.com" with pictures of famous Drupal contributors;

and an example of a site that which does not qualify as fostering the Drupal software:

- publishing a website "drupalhallofshame.com" with pictures of infamous Drupal contributors,"

It seems that what they are trying to accomplish with the enforcement of the trademark in this case is to exclude sites that are using "Drupal" for uses that do not benefit the community. I would argue that a site used to exchange and bubble-up the most reliable information about Drupal would fall into the former category.

Comment: The page I linked reports exactly what Dries means with _fostering_: "You exclusively use the Drupal trademark to either extend or improve the Drupal software, or to encourage the use of the Drupal software (in short "foster the Drupal software")." It doesn't seem a Q&A site does any of those things.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Updated answer to explain why I think this would fall under the first category.

Comment: I'd say that helping people with problems they have with Drupal, thus encouraging them to use it in future projects, is pretty much the definition of encouraging the use of Drupal.

Comment: @Paul Jones: By replying to answers, you are not directly encouraging people to use Drupal; it could be that users, reading some of the questions found on drupal.SE, decide to not use Drupal. A Q&A site should then be "super partes", to be credible.